# Rails: has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am trying to figure out if my approach is proper.  I have a User model and a Compensation Model.  I need to allow the application admin to assign compensation to each User record.  This compensation may change over time and I want to track the changes.  After some research, I thought that the **has_many => :through**  was the way to approach this using a third model called Payments to join the other two and inside that model have the user_id and compensation_id. I have the following set:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :payments
has_many :compensations, :through => :payments


class Compensation < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :payments
has_many :users, :through => :payments

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :Users
has_many :compensations
```

My first question is: Am I correct, that this would be the best approach knowing what I am trying to achieve?  My second question is what is the simplest way to include a drop down field in the form (pooling from the compensation table) that would populate the Payment Table?  Unfortunately, most web discussions I have reviewed about **has_many :through** centers on the models and not the view.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :payments
 has_many :compensations, :through => :payments
end

class Compensation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
  has_many :users, :through => :payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :compensation
end
```

Try this may be it's helpful for you.
More info. see this video - [has_many->through](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks.  That was a mistyp on my part.  I have actually watched that video, but unfortunately it did not guide me on after creating the relationship the next step of getting it to function using a view or at least I did not think it did.  I will take another look.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what your goal is.  Why would a user have many compensations?  Why would a compensation have many users, wouldn't any particular compensation be for a specific user being compensated?  I'm also not sure what form you're talking about in your second question.

That said, assuming you want something that does something similar to your code above, you would just need:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :compensations
end

class Compensation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

As for the dropdown, look into Rails `select` helpers.  Sorry I can't be more specific, again, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post.  Maybe this will help and I may be using the wrong method.  User A is assigned a Compensation by the admin lets say $100.  This compensation will be used for display purposes in the application. Two months from now, User A has his compensation increased by the admin to $200.  If increases continue to occur, I would like to be able to track ewwhen they occurred and at a given time be able to show a history of their occurence.  I was using the has_many : through because I thought that this was the method you were suppose to use when wanting to keep historical data.

Comment: Because their are multiple Users in the database, I assumed the relationship was has_many both ways ---  Finally, the form I was referring to is the form that would be used by the admin to set the compensation inside a users profile.

Comment: What should the possible values in this drop down be, and will they vary user to user?

Comment: I was hoping to pull the values dynamically if possible from the compensation table.  These values would be the same for all users of the application, although obviously different values would be assigned to different users dependant on selection.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- but went in another direction -- for now I have decided against being able to track history and created a dynamci drop down using collection_select –

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is: Am I correct, that this would be the best approach knowing what I am trying to achieve? 
Ans: This is good approach but you can "polymorphic associations" there for more specific solutions.
Your second question is what is the simplest way to include a drop down field in the form (pooling from the compensation table) that would populate the Payment Table?

Second question is not much clear. Do you want to display value of some attribute?

If so, follow my this example. I think It'll help you.

contact.select :contactable, @member.contacts.map {|r| [r.first_name,r.id] }